# Create a Link Ad for a Facebook object (event url)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

In business manager it's possible to create a Link Ad with a Facebook Event url. I like to do the same with Facebook Ads API but facing a permissions error.

The Ad Creative of an Ad created in business manager looks like this one:

```
{
    "object_story_spec": {
        "page_id": "24188824589????",
        "link_data": {
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/events/25595316793????/",
            "message": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
            "image_hash": "cbb1f226fd5fe47c826dd1cad117????"
        }
    }
}
```

When I am trying to create the same Ad Creative via Ads Api I get an error message like the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "FacebookApiException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1349118,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Disallowed Post Link",
    "error_user_msg": "One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the Stream post URL security app setting. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. Read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/ to learn more about app settings related to security."
  }
}
```

I get the same error if I try to create a Link Post with Graph API separately to use as object_story_id.

We really need this kind of Ads for our business. In stream ads perform much better than display ads. Is there anyway to create ads like this one via Ads API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should check the migration settings for your app to see if "Steam post URL security" is enabled.

This prevents URLs being posted by your app which do not link to a domain listed in your app settings.

[image]